# Re-Potting a Lemon Tree: Almost all leaves turned brown on a hot day

Tags: citrus, lemons

Today I re-potted my lemon tree in the morning. It was a very hot day and getting even warmer on the roof terrace where the tree is. In the early afternoon I many leaves have turned brown. Even the newer ones.
I had re-potted it a week ago and added fertilizer and magnesium to the soil. The tree was dropping some leaves so I was worried that I maybe added too much fertilizer and magnesium salt. So I re-potted it today into citrus plant re-potting soil that comes with the right amount of fertilizer.
Was the combination of reporting and hot weather too much at the same time that the leaves turned brown?
Thank you and best regards,
Jan

Comment: It would be better to do repotting on a less hot day.

Answer (score 3):

Yes definitely. The heat will make the plant wilt and this means it has water loss. The plants usually dry up and turn into a crunchy brown before dying. If you provide some temporary shade this will help immensely! You can get a burlap and put it over the tree and this usually is not expensive. If you don't have a burlap you can use a bed sheet and create some kind of tent to provide shade. Increase the water early in the morning so it can suck in the water throughout the day. I heard that lemon trees like the soil to be slightly acidic so you can fertilize the soil as you are doing and allow some drainage.